# Why my code unreachable?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to write a genealogy program, but I got an error:

```
Warning:(30, 14) Kotlin: Parameter 'args' is never used
Warning:(32, 9) Kotlin: Unreachable code
```

How do I fix it?

```
data class Person(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String
) {

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val person = Person(1, "Nikolay")
        println("my name is ${person.name}")
    }
}
```

I could not figure out how to make it work.

Waw, it works!

```
data class Person(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val gender: Int,
        val father: Int,
        val mother: Int,
        val children: List<Int>,
        val email: String,
        val homepage: String,
        val date_of_birth: String,
        val date_of_death: String,
        val is_living: Boolean,
        val place_of_birth: String,
        val place_of_death: String,
        val cemetery: String,
        val schools: List<String>,
        val jobs: List<String>,
        val work_places: String,
        val places_of_living: String,
        val general: String,
        val default_picture: String
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     val person =Person(1, "Nikolay", 1, 10, 11, listOf(2), "mi@ya.ru", 
                        "mishin.narod.ru", "07.02.1976",
                        "", true, "Moscow", "", "", listOf("780", "MIIT"), 
                        listOf("luxoft", "lotus domino"), 
                        "Nagornaya", "Buninskaya Alleya", "perl and kotlin programmer", "")
    println("my name is ${person.name}")
}
```

but also question with Date time
how use it?
is it support Kotlin?

Comment: What do you try to accomplish?

Comment: I try to write geneology program, which read date from csv and build tree in browser, in perl I using  Plack, but what I can use in Kotlin? Spring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want create a new instance of Person in the main method, you need to move your main function out of the class to the package level:

```
data class Person(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person = Person(1, "Nikolay")
    println("my name is ${person.name}")
}
```

Now you can play with Kotlin.